# No relations in entity classes created with NetBeans from database

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans to create entity class from database, I select all table in my database and the classes are created without any information about relations, like @OneToMany, @ManyToOne etc...
This is an example of two tables I have in my DB, is there anything else I need to specify in the tables creation?

```
CREATE TABLE `Indicator` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ApplicablePeriodTypeID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IndicatorSourceID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `IndicatorSourceID` (`IndicatorSourceID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$

CREATE TABLE `IndicatorSource` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CollectionName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `URL` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `SourceName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add a foreign key constraint, e.g. on `IndicatorSourceID`. Otherwise there's no hint that `IndicatorSourceID` refers to `IndicatorSource.ID`.

Comment: sorry if it is a stupid question but I have run this:" Alter table Indicator add CONSTRAINT foreign key (IndicatorSourceID) references IndicatorSource(ID) " , is this what you mean? id doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Yes, I meant this, although you should add a name for the foreign key. This at least tells the database that there is a connection between `Indicator` and `IndicatorSource`. I'm not sure if Netbeans is able to process that information, though.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ENGINE to InnoDB and adding the foreign keys solved the problem. some db engine different from InnoDB dont support foreign key and when trying to add one, it doesn't generate any error.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note: It seems the create entity classes from database feature in Netbeans 6.9 doesn't add relationships for foreign keys migrated from alternate keys -- only those migrated from primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?? Are you sure you have configure the database connection using 
compatible driver to your database and jdk version...